# what does [sock] = func() mean?

Tags: python, syntax, tornado

What does [this line](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/testing.py#L80) of code mean, from `tornado`?

```
[sock] = netutil.bind_sockets(None, 'localhost', family=socket.AF_INET)
```

I understand these assignments: `list[index] = val`, `list[index1:index2] = list2`, but I've never seen that from Tornado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function returns an element inside a container, and the author wants `sock` bound to the element, not to the container.

Here is a more simple example of that syntax:

```
>>> def foo():
...   return ['potato']
... 
>>> [p] = foo()
>>> p
'potato'
```

Comment: Note that this syntax is exactly equivalent to, and as general as, tuple unpacking. In particular, both work for any kind of iterable (e.g. `def foo(): yield 'potato'` or `[p] = map(str.lower, {'potato'})`).

Answer (score 2):

Here, it equals to:

```
sock, = netutil.bind_sockets(None, 'localhost', family=socket.AF_INET)
```

right hand side only contains one element.